# Etymology of 'clinical' in 'clinical professor'?

Tags: etymology

I searched for the meaning of 'clinical' and I could not find any association with academia. Why are non-tenure track jobs referred to as 'clinical'? What is the etymology?

Comment: What is a "clinical professor" in this question? In the UK, it would be a professor of clinical medicine at a university hospital.

Comment: Do you have a link to a website discussing such a job? It is not a general term. I agree with Andrew Leach about the probable meaning.

Comment: [Here](https://jobs.uic.edu/job-board/job-details?jobID=46877&job=clinical-assistant-professor-of-math-ed-mathematics-statistics-and-computer-science) is a job posting for a "Clinical Assistant Professor of Mathematics Education" at a major US university.  I've seen this term used within academia (at least in the US) to refer to jobs that do not require conducting research.  Maybe it is verging on technical jargon but this usage does exist, and I think it's reasonable to ask how it arose.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Maybe in the US, it has a different sense. See [this business school faculty list](http://mays.tamu.edu/directory/) for example, where several professors are referred to as 'clinical'.

Answer (score 3):

A clinical professorship is ordinarily a rank in schools of medicine.  Appointees are expected to teach from a perspective of medical practice (hence the term "clinical") rather than research.  The "major US university" of which Nate Eldredge speaks (The University of Illinois at Chicago) has a medical school, and [here](http://www.uic.edu/depts/mcam/fa/norms/assocprof_ClinDisc.pdf) (emphasis mine) are the requirements for the clinical track:

> The **Clinical** Discipline Track is used in the clinical departments
>   for faculty who are primarily involved in *patient care, teaching, and
>   service*....  Faculty at the Associate Professor of Clinical
>   Discipline rank should have demonstrated excellence in *teaching* and
>   *patient care* programs including development of a high quality and
>   substantial *clinical practice*. Alternatively, this rank may be used
>   to recognize only excellence in *educational activities*.

The clinical track is established in the by-laws of the University and is thus available to faculty outside the medical school.  This is handy because in the US, tenure-track faculty (i.e., those who are seeking tenure) by and large loath teaching.  It's time consuming and unproductive because tenure will be awarded based on research results and publication, not excellence in teaching.  And, to be fair, teaching does require at least some interaction with students.  Academic departments like to offload teaching responsibilities to those who can't compete for tenure, like graduate assistants, part-time faculty, adjuncts, and clinical professors.  Thus from the UIC "Guidelines and Procedures for Appointments and Promotion within the Clinical Academic Ranks" of the School of Liberal Arts and Sciences," we have (with emphasis again mine):

> Appointments to the **clinical** faculty track include Clinical Assistant
>   Professor, Clinical Associate Professor, and Clinical Professor. As
>   specified in the University Statutes (IX.3.c), clinical track
>   contracts *do **not** carry tenure eligibility or tenure status*. The
>   clinical track is intended to stimulate and reward excellence in
>   *teaching* and clinical/professional *practice*<sup>1</sup> activities, and to
>   promote and credit contributions in the areas of research/scholarship
>   and service as appropriate.  For appointment, reappointment, and
>   promotion on this track, a faculty member should show considerable
>   involvement in *teaching* and *practice*.

Footnote 1 reads:

> Practical aspects of the clinical rank may include basic language
>   program direction, teacher education, internship program direction,
>   laboratory supervision and other forms of professional practice, as
>   well as more traditional clinical responsibilities.

As a parallel to medical-school faculty whose expertise is medical practice, "clinical" here denotes those faculty members appointed to teach because of their expertise in the practical aspects of their field.

Answer (score -1):

From [Oxford Dictionaries online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/clinical):

> Late 18th century: from Greek *klinikē* ‘bedside’ (see clinic) + -al.

Comment: Hi, jason, and welcome to English Language & Usage. At this site it is important to site your sources when you quote language from them. I have added a citation and link to the source of of the etymological information you provided in your original answer. Please use a similar approach when crediting sources in future answers. Thanks!